# java spring framework knowledge consolidation

Tags: java, spring

I recently followed some spring related tutorials and I get the feeling that I will forget the concepts learnt so far quickly, since projects I am engaged in at the moment, do not use spring.

I would love to consolidate the things I have learnt and stay in touch with spring. My question is what kind of a project should I start in order cover most of the concepts that I learnt in spring?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a Project for yourself. A photo sharing app for example. This is how I do it. I think of a project for myself and code it in my free time - thus stay in touch with Spring for example.

btw, my last project using spring has now over 100 registered users, which I did not expect and they all demand other functionality - this way you have to improve also.

I might suggest **openshift** as your deploy environment - it's free with plugins for eclipse.
You might also ask/answer spring related questions here on SO - this is always helpful of course.

Answer (score 1):

Think about some examples and try to resolve with spring, Write blogs about spring, contribute some open source projects that use spring. This is the way that I learn spring and still doing. :)